how is it possible that "winfo width $w" provides a width that is different from "$w cget -width" ? which one is the real width displayed?
in TCL TK I have a huge gui that I'm trying to explore. using a tcl procedure that does the exploration, I noticed that winfo and cget provides différents information for width parameter of widgets. how is it possible ? which one is the real width of the widget ?
bonus question : sometimes I have some frame widget that don't have the width parameter: I have an error where trying to configure it or trying to read it (cget). how is it possible as some other frames don't have this problem.
for instance, here the width is different :
-children of .main.frame are :
-widget_path = .main.frame.note
-class (winfo) = NoteBook
-name (winfo) = note
-width (winfo) = 1068
-height (winfo) = 685
-manager (winfo) = pack
-width_cget = 2000
-using configure to configure width at 2000 of .main.frame.note :
-width_cget = 2000
-height (winfo) = 685

also here I have some frame that have width parameter :
                                        ##########################
                                        -children of .main.frame.note.fedac32.pw.f0.frame.pwhoutil.f1.frame.frame_fichiers.l are :
                                        -end of children of .main.frame.note.fedac32.pw.f0.frame.pwhoutil.f1.frame.frame_fichiers.l
                                    -widget_path = .main.frame.note.fedac32.pw.f0.frame.pwhoutil.f1.frame.frame_fichiers.f
                                    -class (winfo) = Frame
                                    -name (winfo) = f
                                    -width (winfo) = 1
                                    -height (winfo) = 1
                                    -manager (winfo) = pack
                                    -width_cget = 2000
                                    -using configure to configure width at 2000 of .main.frame.note.fedac32.pw.f0.frame.pwhoutil.f1.frame.frame_fichiers.f :
                                    -width_cget = 2000
                                    -height (winfo) = 1

and another frame that don't have :
                                        ##########################
                                        -children of .main.frame.note.fedac32.pw.f0.frame.pwhoutil.f1.frame.frame_fichiers.f are :
                                        -widget_path = .main.frame.note.fedac32.pw.f0.frame.pwhoutil.f1.frame.frame_fichiers.f.swf
                                        -class (winfo) = Frame
                                        -name (winfo) = swf
                                        -width (winfo) = 1
                                        -height (winfo) = 1
                                        -manager (winfo) = pack
                                        -@E: impossible to read with cget the width of .main.frame.note.fedac32.pw.f0.frame.pwhoutil.f1.frame.frame_fichiers.f.swf: unknown option "-width"
                                        -using configure to configure width at 2000 of .main.frame.note.fedac32.pw.f0.frame.pwhoutil.f1.frame.frame_fichiers.f.swf :
                                        -@E: impossible to configure widthet 2000 for .main.frame.note.fedac32.pw.f0.frame.pwhoutil.f1.frame.frame_fichiers.f.swf: unknown option "-width"
                                        -@E: impossible to read with cget the width of .main.frame.note.fedac32.pw.f0.frame.pwhoutil.f1.frame.frame_fichiers.f.swf: unknown option "-width"
                                        -height (winfo) = 1

how is it possible ?

There are three concepts of width (and height) going on:

The default width, as configured manually by the -width option on some widgets,
The requested width, as reported by winfo reqwidth — it depends on what the geometry manager calculates from the interior widgets when it has geometry propagation enabled, or uses the default width otherwise — and
The actual width, as set by the parent container or the window manager and as reported by winfo width. This is accurate, but is only ever updated by asynchronous events; it starts out with a nonsense value (can't remember if it is 0 or 1) before the window is first mapped.

You are asking about the default geometry. It's one of the inputs for the geometry calculations, along with any requested sizes from contained widgets. Mostly for containers, you want them to wrap their contents efficiently, so propagated geometry overrides explicitly set geometry. The actual geometry comes along later, once an actual size is known (and is updated whenever the user resizes the window too) but you need to wait for things to be mapped for that to be sensible (technically, you are waiting for a <Configure> event, but mostly you don't need to know about that except if you want to have more direct control of layout changes in that case).

I have a partial answer :
winfo width indicate the real size of the windows where as cget provides the value that is configured.
I still don't know why two frames classes like a frame could have the width parameter or not having the width parameter.
